# AWS ELB Logs not showing 5xx errors in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am seeing an strange issues with AWS ELB, I am getting High-Sum-HTTP-5XX from ELB but when I go to log I do not see any request in access log which have 5XX errors.

Does elb access log does not have 5XX errors reported there. Where can I see which request were having 5XX error it will help me to find root cause. I do not see anything in my server log as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm speculating, you are running a CLB (Classic Load Balancer). The access log with HTTP 5xx errors entries should be analyzed using elb_status_code and a backend_status_code
entries.

This could be off the topic but from [AWS's documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-http-5xx/), it looks like some of these HTTP messages cannot be parsed by Classic Load Balancer (This could happen if there is reverse proxy in place on the instance that is sending an error that the ELB doesn't understand and hence are not recorded in the access logs. I could see the 404 errors in the access logs).